# SQL INSERT INTO SELECT, combine varchar columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table with columns firstName and lastName. Is it possible to do an `INSERT INTO newTable SELECT firstName, lastName FROM oldTable`, but instead of having two columns in the resulting table, concatenate the two columns?

Similarly, is it possible to concatenate a column with a static string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you'd do

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(firstName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(lastName, ''))) FROM oldTable
```

this concatinates the firstName and lastName columns, as well as the static string `' '` in between

EDIT: added `LTRIM(RTRIM(...))` so if firstName or lastName is null, result won't have leading or trailing space as a result from the static `' '` string.

Comment: beware of `NULL` values though... `NULL` concatenated with something else yields `NULL`

Comment: Perfect, didn't know I could do that. And thanks for the heads up Darren

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and if you have a static string or a variable you can say:

```
DECLARE @variable VARCHAR(255);

SET @variable = 'some string';

INSERT INTO dbo.NewTable(column name) 
SELECT 
  COALESCE(firstname, '') + ' ' + COALESCE(lastname, '') + @variable + 'static string' 
FROM dbo.OldTable;
```